# Unable to connect to gitlab, Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have created ssh keys on unbuntu  under `id_company` and `id_company.pub`, and updated config as:

```
Host gitlab.company.com
  Hostname gitlab.company.com
  #PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_company
```

Now, I am trying to test the connection using: `ssh -T git@gitlab.company.com`, But I am receiving `ssh: connect to host gitlab.company.com port 22: Connection timed out` I don't know what might be causing it, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since the connection is timed out, the issue seems to be network related. 
maybe try testing the connection first?
telnet  gitlab.company.com 22

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first your `gitlab.company.com` server is accessible through port 22:

```
curl -v telnet://gitlab.company.com:22
```

I know in my company, no SSH access would ever be granted: HTTPS only.